# Spring Boot Remove exception attribute from error responses

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some exception in order to handling errors in my restful spring backend, Here is example of an exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
public class IllegalUserAgentException extends RuntimeException
{
    public IllegalUserAgentException(String exception)
    {
        super(exception);
    }

}
```

When i throw this exception from service (in domain driven architecture), Spring returning below json error

```
{
    "timestamp": 1552127820802,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "exception": "com.example.exception.IllegalUserAgentException",
    "message": "test",
    "path": "/path/somePath"
}
```

As you can see, Spring added an attribute with "exception" name, I want to remove this attribute.
I added `server.error.include-exception=false` flag, but not work.
Any solution?

Comment: I would advice to implement a global exceptional handler in your project. Here's a good article for a quickstart [global_error_handler](https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api)

Comment: @Ali check if this link can help you https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Answer (score 1):

In spring-boot you can do it via defining a @Component which extends DefaultErrorAttributes, then override the getErrorAttributes function to remove the "exception".

```
@Component
public class CustomErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(
        WebRequest webRequest,
        boolean includeStackTrace
    ) {
        Map<String, Object> errorAttributes
            = super.getErrorAttributes(webRequest, includeStackTrace);
        errorAttributes.remove("exception");
        return errorAttributes;
    }

}
```

There is also another alternatives such as using @ControllerAdvice which you can peruse further.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make a Response Class.
Add try catch in your service class and return this object instead.
In catch section instantiate ResponseDto object and add the message accordingly.This will gracefully handle your exception. It is scalable because you can wrap any other exception message as well.

```
public class ResponseDto {

    @JsonProperty("url")
    private String url;

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private int status;

    @JsonProperty("userMsg")
    private String UserMsg;
}
```